# How to specify CPU(s) and memory resources per node in a multi node cluster in Minikube

Tags: minikube

Minikube allows the creation of multi-node cluster, either using the `--nodes` argument in the `start` command, or my using the `node` command.

It also allows specifying the number of cpus and the amount of memory to be allocated "to kunerbetes" in the `start` command.

However, the documentation does not specify what it means "kubernetes" in this context. All nodes? If so, how are the resources split between the nodes or are they shared?

In other words, if I create a cluster with 2 nodes and assign 4 CPUs, how many CPUs are assigned to one node? It is possible for one node to use more than 2 CPUS?

What I would like is a way to specify the resources to be allocated to each node individual node.

Is this possible?